# HTML, CSS, Jquery help needed

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, submenu

Hey in my last topic I made a mistake by not putting the css and Jquery in it.
So i've tyed a little more and build a menu in CodePen.

Now the problem i've is that still it doesnt work.
I searched but coudn't find it so thats why i put it here.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/djwih

HTML is good, css probely not and i'm almost sure that the jquery is good.
Can someone check this for me and correct my mistakes?

On the top i've a logo on the left side and menu has to be on the right side.
The menu has in the correct html an width of 1200px and is margin:0 auto;.
But the logo is on the same height as the menu so that's why i've put #menu ul float:right;.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title, put your code (not just a link) in the question, and explain the problem in clearly. This is the reason your last question was closed. You should edit that question and then request that it be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are several typos in your jQuery:

```
$function() { 
$(this).find('ul').fadeOut('fast');
}));;
```

remove the `$` from in front of `function`

```
function() {
```

and add a the missing `}` in-between the `))` and remove the additional `;`

```
})});
```

Next, we should classify top-level menu items with the `toplevel` class, and adjust CSS/jQuery accordingly.
HTML:

```
<li class="toplevel"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
<li class="toplevel"><a href="#">Who are we</a>
<li class="toplevel"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Also, set the `margin-left` of the child `ul` elements to `-40px` (for spacing)
CSS:

```
#menu li.toplevel {
display:inline-block;
padding:8px 12px;
list-style:none;
}
```

and

```
#menu ul li ul {
display:block; 
position:absolute;
margin-left:-40px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $('#menu ul li ul').hide();
    $('#menu ul li').hover( 
        function() {
            $(this).find('ul:first').fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function() { 
            $(this).find('ul').fadeOut('fast');
        }
    )
}
);
```

Here is a working jsFiddle with your code cleaned up:
http://jsfiddle.net/9CBs2/1/

Everything seems to work the way you intended. Make *sure* you use a JavaScript debugger or tool to check for syntax errors.